# Command line progress bar in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently trying to add a progress bar to a command line script and I've tried various solutions (including Zend and Console_ProgressBar). The problem they both have in common is that the progress bar doesn't stick at the bottom of the window because during the script, new lines and other information is outputted.

Is there any way to keep the progress bar at the bottom of the terminal but still be able to output other information while the script is running?

[Edit]

I figured it out:

Instead of outputting directly to STDOUT I am actually grabbing the output inside a variable, I erase the screen with `echo chr(27) . '[2J'` and then output to STDOUT the contents of the variable and then append my progress bar.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: I just released my progressbar: https://github.com/Ex3v/PHP-ProgressBar

Answer (score 102):

This is nice progress bar for cli:

http://snipplr.com/view/29548/

```
<?php
 
/*
 
Copyright (c) 2010, dealnews.com, Inc.
All rights reserved.
 
Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * Neither the name of dealnews.com, Inc. nor the names of its contributors
   may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
   without specific prior written permission.
 
THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 
 */
 
/**
 * show a status bar in the console
 * 
 * <code>
 * for($x=1;$x<=100;$x++){
 * 
 *     show_status($x, 100);
 * 
 *     usleep(100000);
 *                           
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * @param   int     $done   how many items are completed
 * @param   int     $total  how many items are to be done total
 * @param   int     $size   optional size of the status bar
 * @return  void
 *
 */
 
function show_status($done, $total, $size=30) {
 
    static $start_time;
 
    // if we go over our bound, just ignore it
    if($done > $total) return;
 
    if(empty($start_time)) $start_time=time();
    $now = time();
 
    $perc=(double)($done/$total);
 
    $bar=floor($perc*$size);
 
    $status_bar="\r[";
    $status_bar.=str_repeat("=", $bar);
    if($bar<$size){
        $status_bar.=">";
        $status_bar.=str_repeat(" ", $size-$bar);
    } else {
        $status_bar.="=";
    }
 
    $disp=number_format($perc*100, 0);
 
    $status_bar.="] $disp%  $done/$total";
 
    $rate = ($now-$start_time)/$done;
    $left = $total - $done;
    $eta = round($rate * $left, 2);
 
    $elapsed = $now - $start_time;
 
    $status_bar.= " remaining: ".number_format($eta)." sec.  elapsed: ".number_format($elapsed)." sec.";
 
    echo "$status_bar  ";
 
    flush();
 
    // when done, send a newline
    if($done == $total) {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
 
}
 
?>
```

Comment: This is so the best answer

Comment: Very much so. As a summary, the important portion of that code snippet is echoing out `"\r"` (double quotes are required) before writing out the new line.

Comment: Worse thing about that function is that you typically start a for loop with $c=0, not $c=1. Since you start with $c=0, you get a Division by Zero exception with the function.

Comment: Very important: this will *not* work if you use a tty whose width is too "small". In fact, in that case, if the long line causes a new-line, the \r just moves to the beginning of the *new* line, not on the first line. The result is a mess.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed

Comment: 25 years of programming and I just realized I can do progress bar with `\r`

Answer (score 55):

Other answers seem overly complex. My solution is to simply echo \033[0G escape sequence before the next update and it moves the cursor back to the beginning.

```
function progressBar($done, $total) {
    $perc = floor(($done / $total) * 100);
    $left = 100 - $perc;
    $write = sprintf("\033[0G\033[2K[%'={$perc}s>%-{$left}s] - $perc%% - $done/$total", "", "");
    fwrite(STDERR, $write);
}
```

Calling the function for the first time outputs the progress bar and each subsequent call overwrites the last line with a new progress bar.

EDIT:
I have changed echoing \r to the escape sequence \033[0G and this should now work on OSX as well as Linux/Unix.

EDIT 2:
Fixed possible error on line 3 as per [@tbjers suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124195/command-line-progress-bar-in-php#comment48370334_27147177).

EDIT 3:
Updated with new version that prints to STDERR and now also on GitHub: https://github.com/MacroMan/PHPTerminalProgressBar

EDIT 4:
Now with composer: `composer require macroman/terminal-progress-bar`

```
use TerminalProgress\Bar;

$pg = new Bar(1000);

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    usleep(10000);
    $pg->tick();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but new lines keep being added. Tested on Mac PHP CLI

Comment: osx uses \r as carriage return and line feed, so this won't work on osx.

Comment: Line 3 should be changed to the following to avoid warnings from `str_repeat`: `$bar = "[" . ($perc > 0 ? str_repeat("=", $perc - 1) : '') . ">";`

Comment: Thanks @tbjers I have added your code to check for below 0 input.

Comment: I would use ceil() function to be sure you get to 100% `function progressBar($done, $total) {
    $perc = ceil(($done / $total) * 100); etc...`

Comment: I don't mind it, but I must confirm it always prints another status line when there's an output in the script. and it DELETEs the last line. It would be nice if it kept all the other outoput and would at least delete the old ones or something like that, but I guess that would have to be done before/with the outputs... tempfix for data loss - print extra `PHP_EOL` after every output/echo

Answer (score 14):

The following is for **unix machines**.

The goal is to retrieve the current terminal total columns. (using `tput`)

This is a base, ready to be expanded.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

@ob_start();
 
$shell = system("tput cols");
 
@ob_end_clean();
  
for( $i= 0 ; $i < $shell ; $i++ ){ echo "█"; usleep(100000); }
```

[image]

The `ob` actions are here to hide the `stdout` of `tput`.

Let's say you would like to make a progress bar matching your task progress.

Just **divide** the remaining time in seconds by the numbers of columns.

You may end up with microseconds, so it's best to use `usleep`.

This way the progress bar will always match the user shell width, including when resized.

To do the same thing in pure bash:

```
for ((i=0; i<$(tput cols); i++)); do echo -e "█\c"; sleep 0.1; done
```

This shows the main singularity of the php `echo`: it does not append a new line, while the bash `echo` does.

When using loops, say to check for a condition in intervals,
one other nice way to warn for running activity is **text effects**.

The following using `strtoupper` and the ansi code **reverse video**.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$iloop = "0"; /* Outside the loop */
while (true){  
  $warn = "Program running hold on!!\r";
  if (strlen($warn) === $iloop+1){
    $iloop = "0";
  }
  $warn = str_split($warn);
  $iloop++;
  $warn[$iloop] = "\033[35;2m\e[0m".strtoupper($warn[$iloop]);
  echo " \033[7m".implode($warn);
  usleep(90000);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Some may likes the party version, obtained by iteration of ansi codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$iloop = "0"; /* Outside the loop */
while (true){    
for ($i=0;$i<=109;$i++){
  $warn = "Program running hold on!!\r";
  if (strlen($warn) === $iloop+1){
    $iloop = "0";
  }
  $warn = str_split($warn);
  $iloop++;
  $warn[$iloop] = "\033[$i;7m".strtoupper($warn[$iloop]);
  echo " \033[7m".implode($warn);
  usleep(90000);
}}
```

[image]

See more about **ANSI** codes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365998/2494754

Answer (score 5):

This is an improvement of the previous answer which handles terminal resizes and uses 2 lines instead of 1. First line is info like time/percent second line is the progress bar.

```
<?
/*

Copyright (c) 2010, dealnews.com, Inc.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
   notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
   documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * Neither the name of dealnews.com, Inc. nor the names of its contributors
   may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
   without specific prior written permission.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 */

/**
 * show a status bar in the console
 *
 * <code>
 * for($x=1;$x<=100;$x++){
 *
 *     show_status($x, 100);
 *
 *     usleep(100000);
 *
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * @param   int     $done   how many items are completed
 * @param   int     $total  how many items are to be done total
 * @param   int     $size   optional size of the status bar
 * @return  void
 *
 */

function show_status($done, $total, $size=30, $lineWidth=-1) {
    if($lineWidth <= 0){
        $lineWidth = $_ENV['COLUMNS'];
    }

    static $start_time;

    // to take account for [ and ]
    $size -= 3;
    // if we go over our bound, just ignore it
    if($done > $total) return;

    if(empty($start_time)) $start_time=time();
    $now = time();

    $perc=(double)($done/$total);

    $bar=floor($perc*$size);

    // jump to the begining
    echo "\r";
    // jump a line up
    echo "\x1b[A";

    $status_bar="[";
    $status_bar.=str_repeat("=", $bar);
    if($bar<$size){
        $status_bar.=">";
        $status_bar.=str_repeat(" ", $size-$bar);
    } else {
        $status_bar.="=";
    }

    $disp=number_format($perc*100, 0);

    $status_bar.="]";
    $details = "$disp%  $done/$total";

    $rate = ($now-$start_time)/$done;
    $left = $total - $done;
    $eta = round($rate * $left, 2);

    $elapsed = $now - $start_time;


    $details .= " " . formatTime($eta)." ". formatTime($elapsed);

    $lineWidth--;
    if(strlen($details) >= $lineWidth){
        $details = substr($details, 0, $lineWidth-1);
    }
    echo "$details\n$status_bar";

    flush();

    // when done, send a newline
    if($done == $total) {
        echo "\n";
    }

}
```

I don't know why the above code has a license I'm just copying it to be safe. The bellow code is under no license. Free to use for any purpose.

```
function formatTime($sec){
    if($sec > 100){
        $sec /= 60;
        if($sec > 100){
            $sec /= 60;
            return number_format($sec) . " hr";
        }
        return number_format($sec) . " min";
    }
    return number_format($sec) . " sec";
}


class Timer {
    public $time;
    function __construct(){
        $this->start();
    }
    function start($offset=0){
        $this->time = microtime(true) + $offset;
    }
    function seconds(){
        return microtime(true) - $this->time;
    }
};


// We need this to limit the frequency of the progress bar. Or else it
// hugely slows down the app.
class FPSLimit {
    public $frequency;
    public $maxDt;
    public $timer;
    function __construct($freq){
        $this->setFrequency($freq);
        $this->timer = new Timer();
        $this->timer->start();
    }
    function setFrequency($freq){
        $this->frequency = $freq;
        $this->maxDt = 1.0/$freq;
    }
    function frame(){
        $dt = $this->timer->seconds();
        if($dt > $this->maxDt){
            $this->timer->start($dt - $this->maxDt);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

class Progress {
    // generic progress class to update different things
    function update($units, $total){}
}

class SimpleProgress extends Progress {
    private $cols;
    private $limiter;
    private $units;
    private $total;

    function __construct(){
        // change the fps limit as needed
        $this->limiter = new FPSLimit(10);
        echo "\n";
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->draw();
    }

    function updateSize(){
        // get the number of columns
        $this->cols = exec("tput cols");
    }

    function draw(){
        $this->updateSize();
        show_status($this->units, $this->total, $this->cols, $this->cols);
    }

    function update($units, $total){
        $this->units = $units;
        $this->total = $total;
        if(!$this->limiter->frame())
            return;
        $this->draw();
    }
}


// example

$tasks = rand() % 700 + 600;
$done = 0;

$progress = new SimpleProgress();

for($done = 0; $done <= $tasks; $done++){
    usleep((rand() % 127)*100);
    $progress->update($done, $tasks);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! The `\x1b[A` bit is just what I needed to have multiline progress bar :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something that can be used in different terminals without having to worry about compatibility, Ncurses is the way to go.

Check: https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/ncurses/

`The ncurses library provides a robust framework which allows programmers to create visually appealing user interfaces in text mode`

Main PHP documentation point about this is: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Progress";
    $progress = false;
    while ($progress==false){
    echo ".";
    sleep(1);
    }
    
       #enter code here
    
    $progress == true; 
    if($progress == true){
    # Do something only when done 
    # Code here
   echo " Done!";
    }
```