# What does [%'={$percentageDone}s>%-{$percetageLeft}s] mean?

Tags: php, bash, ansi-escape

I found this cool progress bar I'm using:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147177/1480397

But I have no clue what it is doing and I'm failing to google it.

```
"\r\033[0G\033[2K[%'={$percentageDone}s>%-{$percetageLeft}s] -   $percentageDone%% - $absoluteDone/$absoluteTotal - avg %.4f - %s",
```

This is what I'm using.

I think the sequences are:

- `\r` - carriage return, go back to start
- `\033[0G` - `Esc[0g`  Clear a tab at the current column` *
- `\033[2K`- `Esc[2K`   Clear entire line *
- `[%'={$percentageDone}s>%-{$percetageLeft}s]`

`*` This doesn't do what I expect, when I remove the code, Source: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

So, are these sequences extracted correctly? Is the interpretation correct? And why is the last writing cool bars?

```
[====>                                       <much more spaces>       ]
```

Code to test:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $absoluteDone = $i;
    $absoluteTotal = 100;
    $percentageDone = floor(($absoluteDone / $absoluteTotal) * 100);
    $percetageLeft = 100 - $percentageDone;
    $avgTime = 10;
    $setCursorToLineStart = "\033[0G";
    $clearLine = "\033[2K";
    $progressbarAndStatusInfo = sprintf(
        $setCursorToLineStart
        . $clearLine
        . "[%'={$percentageDone}s>%-{$percetageLeft}s] - $percentageDone%% - $absoluteDone/$absoluteTotal - avg %.4f - %s",
        "",
        "",
        $avgTime,
        gmdate("H:i:s", $avgTime * ($absoluteTotal - $absoluteDone))
    );

    echo $progressbarAndStatusInfo;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Not sure what is wrong. I have four escape sequences which I need to understand? What is broad about this question?

Comment: provide context for the "code" (`sprintf` !)

Comment: Looks like it's trying to mimic ncurses style updates. Write a line with various lengths of '=' followed by spaces to fill the line. Then carriage return, clear and repeat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ansi escape codes look correct to me, however:

```
[%'={$percentageDone}s>%-{$percetageLeft}s]
```

has nothing to do with ansi. It's padding via sprintf:

```
'={$percentageDone}
```

will fill the line with x '=' chars, where x is the value in $percentageDone.

See [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) docs for details.