# Error creating progress bar Laravel 5.0 Artisan Commands

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I am trying to create a progress bar in an artisan command. The version of laravel i am using is 5.0 (although it has been updated from 4.x so the commands are stored in the folder app/Console/Commands and are in the namespace Foundry\PhoneHome\Console\Commands)

I am running `$this->output->progressStart($count);` and have also tried `$this->output->createProgressBar($count);` but for both of them i get the error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput::progressStart()`

Am i doing something wrong or are the progress bars not supported in laravel 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bars were entered in Laravel 5.1, you can upgrade your Laravel (recommended) or writing a simple progress bar by yourself.

Inside your command, add the following function:

```
private function updateProgress($done, $total) {
    $perc = floor(($done / $total) * 50);
    $left = 50 - $perc;
    $write = sprintf("\033[0G\033[2K[%'={$perc}s>%-{$left}s] - $perc%% - $done/$total", "", "");
    fwrite(STDERR, $write);
}

public function handle() {
     // your logic
     $this->updateProgress(1,10);
}
```

You can see more implementations here [Command line progress bar in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124195/command-line-progress-bar-in-php)